# MicroTask executed before the current task finishes

Tags: javascript, es6-promise

I have been lately reading about the differences between macro and micro tasks in JavaScript. I stumbled upon a thing I can't understand. In [this article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTML_DOM_API/Microtask_guide#when_to_use_microtasks) there is an example of promise usage in coditionals and how they can affect execution ordering. Here is a short snippet I did to reproduce it on my PC:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <script>
        const root = document.getElementById("root");
        const cache = {};

        root.addEventListener("load", () => console.log("Loaded data"));

        function getData(url) {
            if (cache[url]) {
                root.dispatchEvent(new Event("load"));
            } else {
                Promise.resolve({a: 5}).then(data => {
                    cache[url] = data;
                    root.dispatchEvent(new Event("load"));
                });
            }
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Having the above HTML page open in the browser pase the following code in the console two times.

```js
console.log("Fetching data...");
getData("test");
console.log("Data fetched");
```

The result of this is the following:

```
Fetching data...
Data fetched
Loaded data
Fetching data...
Loaded data
Data fetched
```

I can't quite get why the order of the log statements is different the second time I execute the code. From what I understand micro/macro tasks can't be processed before the current script or task in this case (as far as I know every snippet of code is wrapped in a macrotask which is then processed by the event loop) finishes. I would expect the same order in all cases.

Comment: `root.dispatchEvent(new Event("load"));` does not schedule a (macro or other) task at all, it *synchronously* dispatches the event and returns the event listener results.

Comment: I see now where I got it wrong.. (I assumed it creates a macrotask)